# Using substring to eliminate the directory path is not working

Tags: c#

I need to trim the directory path so that the file only shows up in a `TextBox`. I keep getting an out of range error.

This is the code I have:

```
string startPath = "";
string results = "";

string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\TwinTable\LeftTableO0201", "*.*");

startPath = filePaths.ToString();
results = startPath.Substring(28);

TboxLeftTable.Text = results;
```

The path I am trying to trim is: `C:\TwinTable\LeftTableO0201\3100200210.TA4`

Comment: You just want the filename?  If so, use `Path.GetFileName(someFilePath)`

Comment: `startPath = filePaths.ToString();` just returns the name of the array type.

Comment: Any amount of debugging and you would have found the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use this :

```
string startPath = "";
string results = "";

string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\TwinTable\LeftTableO0201", "*.*");

if (filePaths.Length > 0)
   TboxLeftTable.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePaths[0]);
```

Comment: That works great but I am getting an error if the file doesn't exist  to leave the TboxLeftTable.Text blank! I thought I would do an error check!

Comment: I get an out of range error. The index was outside the bounds of array.

Comment: Please check now, it should be okay now!

Answer (score 2):

First, this is not correct:

```
startPath = filePaths.ToString();
```

since you have an array. 
Instead you should iterate over the array elements.
Your code should be something like this:

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\TwinTable\LeftTableO0201", "*.*");
foreach (string startPath in filePaths)
{
    result = Path.GetFileName(startPath);
    TboxLeftTable.Text += result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling `ToString` on an array results in `System.String[]` ([demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JJoOFV)), in which case index of `28` is out of range (returned string has only 15 characters).

Probably you want to have arrays of trimmed values, in which case you should use LINQ for example:

```
filePaths.Select(s => s.Substring(28)).ToArray();
```

Alternatively, if you want to use just single entry of an array, you should use:

```
startPath = filePaths[0]; //or whatever element you want to use
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be used to get the name of files in a directory to an array (fileNames):

```
var directory = @"C:\TwinTable\LeftTableO0201";
var fileNames = Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory).Select(Path.GetFileName).ToArray();
```

This could possibly be used to set the `Text` property of `TboxLeftTable` object, perhaps:

```
TboxLeftTable.Text = fileNames.First();
```