# Checking to see File exists is not working

Tags: c#

I am trying to check to see if the file exists if it doesn't leave the textbox blank! it doesn't work

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\TwinTable\LeftTableO0201", "*.*");

if (!File.Exists(filePaths.ToString()))
{
    TboxLeftTable.Text = "";
}
else
{
    TboxLeftTable.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePaths[0]);
}
```

Comment: Didnt you just ask [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52653775/using-substring-to-eliminate-the-directory-path-is-not-working) in which everyone told you not to do `filePaths.ToString()`?  You need to provide us with the **desired functionality**, you didnt do that in your earlier question, or here.

Comment: Yes I did but I am not getting the file exists correct it errors on me, I thought I had to ask a new question since it was answered

Comment: Asking a new question is fine.  But you have to tell us what you want your code to do (i.e the **desired functionality**).  What you have now does not make sense, why would you check if the file exists when you know it does since you literally just got the files by calling `GetFiles()`?

Comment: Only one file will ever exist is this file folder if it is deleted I would like it to have a blank response in the textbox

Comment: The problem is that you're using an array incorrectly. You need to understand how to work with arrays. See here for an example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/2pP1vr

Comment: @GNell Ok, but slow down and think for a second.  If you get a list of files that exist in a folder, why would you need to check if the file exists on the _very next line_?  You already know it exists!

Comment: @GNell Probably learning some programming will be a good start.  Your logic is messed up.  You don't know what an array is.

Answer (score 1):

Well, one problem you have is that you are just trying to use `ToString()` on an array. Since `Directory.GetFiles()` returns an array of file names, you need to iterate over those files and check them one at a time. Something like this:

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\TwinTable\LeftTableO0201", "*.*");

foreach (string curFilePath in filePaths)
{
    if (!File.Exists(curFilePath))
    {
        TboxLeftTable.Text = "";
    }
    else
    {
        TboxLeftTable.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(curFilePath);
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider the code OP posted and even your own.  Why would you want to check to see if the file exists?  This really seems like a problem that we cannot answer quite yet because OP does not even seem to know what they need.

Comment: I don't know what OP is trying to do, and I know that my code is redundant. I kept the code very similar to theirs so they can compare and see what the difference is and hopefully learn from it.

Comment: I think we need more information from OP _before_ we can answer it.  Your post solves _some_ of the problem.  We are likely dealing with an XY Problem here

Answer (score 0):

This is the working code. Thanks for the help!

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\TwinTable\LeftTableO0201", "*.*");

if (filePaths.Length > 0)
    TboxLeftTable.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePaths[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Once your code is fixed you still have weird logic. If we take your logic and spell it out in a sentence it reads like this:

> Get a list of files from a folder, then immediately check to see if the file(s) in that folder exist

I think what you want to do instead is:

> Get a list of files from a folder, if one exists display the very first one's name in a textbox, if it does not, display nothing

If I am right, then your code would look like this:

```
// Gets all string file paths in a folder
// then grabs the first one, or null if there are none
string filePath = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\TwinTable\LeftTableO0201", "*.*").FirstOrDefault();

// if the path is not null, empty or whitespace    
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filePath)
{
    // then get the filename and put it in the textbox
    TboxLeftTable.Text = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
}
else
{
    // There were no files in the folder so make the textbox empty
    TboxLeftTable.Text = string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Testing for `null` would be most appropriate. A file path can't be empty or all whitespace